# LongClick in tabs

Tags: android, android-tabhost

In my code I long click some tab to start some activity, the background of the view becomes yellow by default. When I return from the started activity the background of the tab still stays as it is. What should I use to get rid of the yellow background?? And the tab is not long clickable but the view of each tab is long clickable.. this is my code. What should I write before return statement to remove that yellow colour??

```
tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),LongActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                //what should i write here??

                return true;

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't return anything from `onLongClick` that affects the color. The tab color is generally controlled by a state list drawable (see http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html, item number 3 for the basic detail).

I believe what you would have to do is provide your own custom state list drawable that doesn't use the yellow color. You may also need to refresh the screen somehow: I've honestly never seen tabs use `onLongClick` before, so you may have hit some weird state.